# How do I pass an equal sign when calling a batch script in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

We have a batch file that invokes our MSBuild-based build process.  Syntax:

```
build App Target [ Additional MSBuild Arguments ]
```

Internally, it does this:

```
msbuild.exe %1.msbuild /t:%2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Which results in calls to MSBuild that look like this:

```
msbuild.exe App.msbuild /t:Target
```

**When any argument contains the equal sign, `=`, Powershell completely removes it.**  My batch script never sees it.  This does not happen with the standard `cmd.exe` command prompt.

For example, if I call

```
build App Target "/p:Property=Value"
```

this is what gets passed to MSBuild:

```
msbuild.exe App.msmbuild /t:Target /p:Property Value
```

I expected this:

```
msbuild.exe App.msbuild /t:Target "/p:Property=Value"
```

I've tried the Powershell escape character, the standard Command Prompt escape character, and even stuff I made up:

```
build App Target "/p:Property=Value"
build App Target '/p:Property=Value'
build App Target /p:Property^=Value
build App Target /p:Property`=Value
build App Target /p:Property==Value
```

None of it works.  **What do I do to get the equal sign to not be stripped out or removed?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've seen this before and have found a way to *trick* it out. I wish I could explain what's going on in particular with the '=' but I cannot. In your situation I'm fairly certain the following will work if you want to pass properties to msbuild:

```
build App Target '"/p:Property=Value"'
```

When echoed, this produces the following:

```
msbuild.exe App.msbuild /t:Target "/p:Property=Value"
```

Comment: That worked!  I thought I tried that combination, but I guess I just tried only single quotes, not single quotes around double quotes.  Powershell can be quite strange sometimes.

Comment: The problem is that PowerShell does not quote the arguments when passed to executables.  So even though PowerShell knows that "/p:Property=Value" is one string, it passes it without quotes.  This can cause executables to not see it as one argument.  I had the same problem with include quotes in an argument, and I had to \ escape them.

Comment: @jasonmarcher: Agreed, but this seemed to be unique with the '=' as escaping it made no difference. Give it a try and you'll see.

Comment: The quoting is the issue, I'm completely agreeing with you.

Comment: After re-reading your comment, I see what you mean. Sorry, my misunderstanding. :)

Comment: Awesome! Finally managed to get a Git build date which requires an equal sign. The final command for those interested : FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%A IN ('"git show -s --format="%%ci" HEAD"') DO ( @SET BUILD_DATE=%%A )

Answer (score 5):

With [PowerShell 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx) you can use --% to stop the normal parsing powershell does.

```
build --% App Target "/p:Property=Value"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an easier answer (I think not) but you can solve the problem by using .Net's process class to invoke cmd.exe.  Here's an example:

```
# use .NET Process class to run a batch file, passing it an argument that contains an equals sign. 
# This test script assumes the existence of a batch file "c:\temp\test.bat"
# that has this content:
#      echo %1
#      pause
$cmdLine =  $cmdLine =  '/c c:\temp\test.bat "x=1"'
$procStartInfo =  new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $cmdLine )
$proc = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process
$proc.StartInfo = $procStartInfo
$proc.Start();
```

Comment: This won't work.  Invoking the batch file has to be a one line operation, as outlined in my question.

Comment: Well, you could make it a function, then it could be a one-liner.  But I hope scott's answer wroks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried single quotes to force a literal interpretation?

Or:
    cmd /c 'msbuild.exe App.msbuild /t:Target "/p:Property=Value"'

Comment: Invoking a batch file will drop the = sign too, though in this case enclosing in quotes is sufficient to preserve it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that only single-quote around double-quote might be the best for multiple scenario around windows environment.
Following link from MS shows its support(or limitation) of equal sign
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/35938
It is specific to Batch Files but it likely affect lots of other MS shell products.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that `%2` becomes `"/p:property"` and `%3` becomes `"value"`.

Make this work in your batch file by using BOTH `%2` and `%3` and insert an `=` sign between them:

```
msbuild.exe %1.msbuild /t:%2=%3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

and do not use the quote chars on the command line call. Use:

```
build App Target /p:property=value
```

For additional args with `=` signs just keep pairing them up.

I had the same issue with a simple batch file to run youtube-dl where the URL I pass has an `=` sign in it. 
solved as :

```
@echo off
REM YTDL audio only
echo %1=%2
youtube-dl -f bestaudio --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 %1=%2
```