# java via command line cuts MySQL 'equal' operator

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, command-line, rapidminer

Weirdest thing,

I am not sure this is a RapidMiner thing, might be jdbc/java/command-line

I am using RapidMiner 5.3 to run a program I created.

One of the parameters I pass on to the jar file is a MySQL query.

```
java -cp "C:/Program Files (x86)/Rapid-I/RapidMiner5/lib/rapidminer.jar" -Drapidminer.home="C:/Users/Bergkamp/.RapidMiner5/repositories/Bergkamp" com.rapidminer.RapidMinerCommandLine //Bergkamp/processes/projects/FootballProj -Mquery="SELECT a,b FROM tbl_x where a=2"
```

No matter what I do the program uses the query up to the first '=' operator and cuts it to be

```
java -cp "C:/Program Files (x86)/Rapid-I/RapidMiner5/lib/rapidminer.jar" -Drapidminer.home="C:/Users/Bergkamp/.RapidMiner5/repositories/Bergkamp" com.rapidminer.RapidMinerCommandLine //Bergkamp/processes/projects/FootballProj -Mquery="SELECT a,b FROM tbl_x where a"
```

Is that a known issue? Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Can you try that answer please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940375/how-do-i-pass-an-equal-sign-when-calling-a-batch-script-in-powershell

Comment: I was sure that answer will work, but it didn't.
Got anything else up your sleeve?

Comment: No :(. I guess the problem is that the command line tries to handle that `=` as part of an argument. But I don't know how to fix that in Windows.

Comment: Escape it with a ^. Nothing to do with Java.

Comment: the ^ did not work as well. any more ideas?