# How to prevent formatting of parameters to a command in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I want to call a batch file with powershell, like this:

```
$databaseUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://$($databaseConfig.Server):$($databaseConfig.Port);databaseName=$($databaseConfig.Name)"

./database/liquibase/liquibase.bat --url=$databaseUrl
```

My problem is that the `=` is replaced with a whitespace, leaving only `--url` as the first parameter. I try putting it in quotes:

```
.\database\liquibase\liquibase.bat "--url=$databaseUrl"
```

...with the same result. I read that I can use backtick to escape characters:

```
.\database\liquibase\liquibase.bat "--url`=$databaseUrl"
```

...but the equals sign still disappears. I have also tried using `--%` to prevent any formatting from happening:

```
.\database\liquibase\liquibase.bat --% "--url=$databaseUrl"
```

but then the variable `$databaseUrl` is interpreted verbatim.

Any help on how to pass the argument, unformatted, but with variables expanded would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your best option would be to allow the `--url:<value>` syntax as well, if you have the batch file under your control. There are a couple of questions, and comments, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940375/how-do-i-pass-an-equal-sign-when-calling-a-batch-script-in-powershell#comment5552300_4941064) that explain the details of the issue.

Comment: It's too long for a comment, but this is the important part: `java -cp "%CP%" %JAVA_OPTS% liquibase.integration.commandline.Main %CMD_LINE_ARGS%`. When I start the java command from the powershell script, the formatting of the parameters seem to work. I think that is my best bet.

Answer (score 0):

maybe tricky, but as the escape operator `--%` allow environmnent variable expansion you could try this :

```
$env:databaseUrl ="jdbc:sqlserver://$($databaseConfig.Server):$($databaseConfig.Port)"
$env:db="$($databaseConfig.Name)"
.\database\liquibase\liquibase.bat --% "--url=%databaseUrl%;databasename=%db%"
```

Comment: I have been testing with environment variables, but they are still causing problems. Running your example, the batch file gets this input: `--url jdbc:sqlserver://TEST:1433 databaseName SomeDbName`

Comment: tweak  a bit more.... `$env:url="jdbc:sqlserver://server:8080"  ; $env:db="someDBName" ; \liquibase.bat --% "--url=%url%;databasename=%db%"  `

Comment: Now the imput parameter looks like this `"--url=jdbc:sqlserver://server:8080;databasename=someDBName"`. That seems fine, but when the parameter is used to start a java program, it doesn't work. Probably because it is all in a string. Like I commented above, if I start the java process directly from powershell, the parameters are fine. I think I'll go for that.