# Calling Powershell from bat file - ignore special characters in params

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have a bat file and I need to use it to call a powershell script.

I need to pass this powershell script a jdbc connect string which has lots of brackets and @'s. I have made a simple example which demos my problem.

my test.bat is as follows:

```
@PowerShell.exe -Command "C:\off_desk\ci\test\test.ps1 %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9"
```

I use this with test.ps1 which is as follows:

```
Param(
  [string]$one
)

Write-Host "Got $one"
```

When I run:

```
test jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(enable=broken)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=cc-rjmetcal)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(service_name=CITESTDB_001))))
```

I get an error:

```
Missing closing ')' in expression.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInExpression
```

I have tried running with quotes:

```
test "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(enable=broken)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=cc-rjmetcal)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(service_name=CITESTDB_001))))"
```

but this also errors.

I have tried many things I have found on the internet. Surrounding it with @`and @" and various other things. None worked. I am limited by what a bat can do so I can't search the string for all the escape chars and prefix them with`.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I keep counting and counting, but it seems your statement has 9 opening and 10 closing brackets... Does not explain the message you get with a missing closing bracket though...

Comment: The content shouldn't matter. I just want powershell to leave the string alone

Comment: Oops right! During testing powershell complained about a bracket too much nevertheless ;)

Comment: Any particular reason why you constrain yourself to at most nine arguments? Wouldn't `%*` be simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your test.bat to have single quotes around the arguments passed to PowerShell. Run with double quotes as you did before (specifies one argument, no need for `%2 %3` etc)

```
@PowerShell.exe -Command "C:\off_desk\ci\test\test.ps1 '%1'"
```

Answer (score 1):

After testing and searching I found that neither the `@` nor the brackets are causing problems, but the equal signs.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940375/how-do-i-pass-an-equal-sign-when-calling-a-batch-script-in-powershell) is a workaround for that:

Passing your connection string enclosed in first single-quotes and the double-quotes like this:

```
'"connectionstring goes here"'
```

Working with your way (commandline-> batch-file -> powershell) this seems to be working correctly.

Comment: Hi, I re-ran the test with test a=b and the output was just a. I ran it again with test "a=b" and the output was got a=b. I don't think it's the equals signs as none of those tests errored as I described

Comment: The solution you proposed does work. (I tried lots of combinations including "'xxx'" but not the otherway around

Comment: After I tried your example from your question above no equal sign showed up when the error message came up and the problem laid after the last one: after that the connection string just ended. Try it yourself with the string you used above :)