# Python 3.4 sys.argv[1]

Tags: python-3.4

I am passing a URL as the first parameter, to a script. But it will not take the full URL if it contains an equal sign (=). For example if `myscript.py` contains:

```
site = sys.argv[1]
```

and I call

```
myscript.py https://www.google.com/#q=boxing
```

it stops before the equal sign and doesn't take in the full url.

```
site = sys.argv[1]
print(site)
```

output:

```
https://www.google.com/#q=
```

I know I can put the full URL in double quotes and it will get processed, but what to automate passing the parameter and not have to worry about put double quotes.

Could someone please provide some guidance. thanks.

Comment: This works on my linux machine, what OS do you use? Generally, since urls can have meta-characters also used by shells, you have to do something. What do you mean by "automate passing the parameter"? If you are doing that with python, you can use `subprocess.call(['myscript.py', 'https://www.google.com/#q=boxing'])`. On linux you skip a subshell completely and on windows the string is escaped for you.

Comment: I am using 64 bit windows 7 and python 32 bit 3.4 version. Howcould I escape the equal sign, since that seems to be the problem for most of my urls.

Comment: I don't have a windows machine so can't test but I think equal sign is fine for cmd.... are you using power shell? Here's a hint http://stackoverflow.com/a/26194007/642070 but I'm not sure!

Answer (score 0):

I should have been a little more specific, I am calling my python script via a windows batch file. The (=) is a delimiter, and is taking the rest of the URL as a parameter. I was able to fix this by putting double quotes around the URL. I thought python was causing the issue, but it was the windows command prompt all along.